# How to get the selected checkboxes which are dynamically generated using Jquery

Tags: c#, dynamic, checkbox

Hi i have a page which consists of dynamically generated checkboxes using razor code. I need to get the selected checkboxes using Jquery. If there is anything simple than Jquery to achieve this means suggest me.

Comment: when you say "selected checkboxes", do you mean "checked" checkboxes?

Comment: yeah .Checked checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get Check box status (checked/Unchecked) in Jquery  like this

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
alert($(this).is(":checked"))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$( "input[type=checkbox] :checked" )